# MUI Custom named options in palette - Property 'primary' does not exist on type 'TypeBackground'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to extend the MUI palette so I can use my own named properties with the following code:

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    border: Palette['primary']
    background: Palette['primary']
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface PaletteOptions {
    border?: PaletteOptions['primary']
    background?: PaletteOptions['primary']
  }
}
```

`border` works without issues, however since trying to add a new background it does complain about this one.

Full Error:

```
Property 'primary' does not exist on type 'TypeBackground'.  TS2339

     8 | 
     9 | const DocumentUploadContainer = styled('div')`
  > 10 |   color: ${props => props.theme.palette.background.primary};
       |                                                    ^
    11 | `
    12 | export const Documents = () => {
    13 |   return (
```

[image]

Comment: I read somewhere, that background property shares with CSS as image.(something like that) so when adding color to it, it has to be added with attribute 'default' rather than 'main','light'or 'dark' like in other palette colors. you can also check default theme https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/ for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check in file [createPalette.d.ts](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/styles/createPalette.d.ts#L103) of mui.
Because `background` is already in `interface PaletteOptions`, (as you can see here)

```
export interface PaletteOptions {
  primary?: PaletteColorOptions;
  secondary?: PaletteColorOptions;
  error?: PaletteColorOptions;
  warning?: PaletteColorOptions;
  info?: PaletteColorOptions;
  success?: PaletteColorOptions;
  mode?: PaletteMode;
  tonalOffset?: PaletteTonalOffset;
  contrastThreshold?: number;
  common?: Partial<CommonColors>;
  grey?: ColorPartial;
  text?: Partial<TypeText>;
  divider?: string;
  action?: Partial<TypeAction>;
  background?: Partial<TypeBackground>;
  getContrastText?: (background: string) => string;
}
export interface TypeBackground {
  default: string;
  paper: string;
}
```

Hence, you cannot use module augmentation to override it like this. Just use another name.

Comment: Brilliant @Do!! I wish this was in their documentation tbh!!!